# C# : How to send data from the main file to another file and affect them to constructor parameters?

Tags: c#

I am working with 2 **C#** .cs files, the first is the main **program.cs** and the second I use to declare data and constructors.

I have to send data from main function of the program.cs file to the constructor named `ManageVehicule` declared in the other .cs file in order to affect the data sent to `hwManager` and `dao` variables.

How to do that please ?

This is a part of the second file where I am declaring the variables and constructors :

```
//Data
private HardWareV hwManager;
private DaoVehicule dao;

//Region Constrcuture

public ManageVehicule(HardWareV hwV, DaoVehicule daoV)
{
    hwManager = hwV;
    dao = daoV;
}
```

Comment: A constructor is meant to "construct" an instance of class, so you should create an instance of class in your `Main` (or somewhere), and the constructor will be implicitly offered to that.

Comment: `new ManageVehicule(....)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create a instance of `ManageVehicule` type and pass in the required parameter from your `Program.cs` like `ManageVehicule data = new ManageVehicule(new HardWareV( .. ), new DaoVehicule( .. ))`

Comment: This is what I did in main : `ManageVehicule data = new ManageVehicule(new HardWareV( ), new DaoVehicule( ))` but it tells me while compiling `Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface HardWareV ` same for DaoVehicule.

Answer (score 0):

You should declare your `ManageVehicule` class in program.cs, passing your data as parameters for `ManageVehicule` constructor.
e.g.

```
ManageVehicule mv = new ManageVehicule(HwV, DaoV);
```